# How do I install Meshlab 2016.12 or later (current is like 2020.07 which works as well) on Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: 18.04, python, ppa

How do I install Meshlab 2016.12 or later (current is like 2020.07 which works as well) on Ubuntu 18.04? It works fine on Ubuntu 20.04, but I have to do it on 18.04. I need to be able to use meshlabserver from python (MeshLabXML https://github.com/3DLIRIOUS/MeshLabXML) without snap. With snap it works like this (https://github.com/cnr-isti-vclab/meshlab/issues/395)

If you do “sudo apt-get install meshlab”, it installs 1.3.2+dfsg1-4. Now if you do sudo “sudo apt install snapd”, it installs the correct version of meshlab but in the snap directory and can’t be found by MeshLabXML. Also, it installs it as meshlab.meshlabserver instead of meshlabserver.

Now, according to this tutorial, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=G2m61wQqG6M, I can do:

1. sudo add-apt-repository ppa:zarquon42/meshlab   (from here: [https://launchpad.net/~zarquon42/+archive/ubuntu/meshlab](https://launchpad.net/%7Ezarquon42/+archive/ubuntu/meshlab))
2. sudo apt-get update
3. sudo apt-get install meshlab

But this just installs the 1.3.2 version.

There is also building Meshlab from source, but I’m a Linux noob and can’t understand some commands or errors. I found 2 tutorials:

1. https://www.petercheng.net/posts/meshlab-build/
2. https://gist.github.com/LogWell/bffd0a79ff13ec392f8fcf6749388c46

Comment: Have you tried the AppImage? https://github.com/cnr-isti-vclab/meshlab/releases/download/Meshlab-2020.07/MeshLab2020.07-linux.AppImage. The PPA is extremely outdated, so I'm not surprised it didn't work.

Comment: The newest package in that PPA is Xenial (Ubuntu 16.04). That's a dead-end. Uninstall all packages from that source, and then delete that source.

Comment: @ajgringo619 It opens fine and works, but how do you install an AppImage?

Comment: You don't - it's completely self-contained, like a snap/flatpak rolled into one file.

Comment: won't work then. It needs to create a meshlabserver file in the usr/bin folder to be found